# Asp.net mvc 3 add error icon near validation error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add an icon in front of every validation error message.
I am trying this:

```
        public static IHtmlString BogusValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expr)
        {
            ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TProperty>(expr, htmlHelper.ViewData);
            MvcHtmlString validationError = htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(expr);
            var imgErr = new TagBuilder("img");
            imgErr.Attributes.Add("src", "../../Content/images/error.png");
            return new HtmlString(imgErr.ToString() + validationError.ToString());           
        }
```

I get this:

```
<label for="Email">Email address</label>
<input id="Email" type="text" value="" name="Email" data-val-required="The Email address field is required." data-val="true">
<img src="../../Content/images/error.png">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Email"></span
```

I see that error icon from the beginning.
How can i put that img inside the span? How can i access its InnerHtml property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have an easier time using css to apply a background image to spans with `field-validation-error`.

```
.field-validation-error {
    background:url(../../Content/images/error.png) no-repeat left center;
    padding-left:20px; /* or whatever you image size is */
}
```